# Adding virtual lid-close switch to Windows for testing

Tags: c, windows, api, winapi, power-management

I implemented some source code for a very basic event that is registered to be executed on lid-close event in Windows and now want to add some unit tests for it. In windows lid-close do nothing is set so that computer will still be running, etc. My application is already working fine - I tested it some other way, but want to add unit tests for clearness of code.

Is there any kind of way to add a virtual lid-close button to Windows, that I could use to test the actions from my application? I couldn't find anything on the Internet so far so it would be great if one could tell me if and how this is possible. Writing a driver or so is no issue at all - I just want to add the implementation!! Thanks!

Comment: Please read about Windows events and how they are generated, propagated, and handled. There are functions in the API to send any window any message. Since I don't have the time to search the API myself, I don't have a pointer for you here. Anyway, this is your task, too.

Comment: Of course this is what I already tried and couldn't find this specific event and how to send it... So if someone has a more helpful comment please let me know! :)

Comment: Well, since your code reacts on that event, you already know its value and parameters, most probably from its documentation. Why don't you just post that? -- And you might like to [edit] your question with the findings you got so far.

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion is to fake the lid closing by sending/posting the windows message. For example, if you are using [`RegisterPowerSettingNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerpowersettingnotification) to registers a window to receive the lid-close event, Notifications will be sent as [`WM_POWERBROADCAST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/wm-powerbroadcast) messages with a `wParam` parameter of [`PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/pbt-powersettingchange) to your window. You could handle the event in your windows loop:

```
HPOWERNOTIFY lidcloseRegHandle;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        lidcloseRegHandle = RegisterPowerSettingNotification(hWnd, &GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE, DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);
        break;
    case WM_POWERBROADCAST:
        {
            if (wParam == PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE)
            {
                if (IsEqualGUID(powersetting->PowerSetting, GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE))
                {
                    switch (powersetting->Data[0])
                    {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Close", L"event", 0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Open", L"event", 0);
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox(NULL, L"Unknown", L"event", 0);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        UnregisterPowerSettingNotification(lidcloseRegHandle);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

test sample:

```
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL,L"lid-close-notification-window");
POWERBROADCAST_SETTING powersetting = { 0 };
powersetting.PowerSetting = GUID_LIDSWITCH_STATE_CHANGE;
powersetting.DataLength = 1;
powersetting.Data[0] = 0; //close
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_POWERBROADCAST, PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE, (LPARAM)&powersetting);
```

Comment: if I just want to check for the lid state and do something depending on whether it is open or closed, how would I do this? I get pieces of your code but don't know how to put this together...